# Openbox client-menu is not opening at the mouse pointer

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, lxde, openbox

I am running LXDE+Openbox on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with Lubuntu installed.

When I click on the client-menu icon, or right click on the titlebar, the client menu opens far to the left of the mouse cursor. It is always a fixed offset from the mouse cursor, about 2/3 of a monitor width. (Unless I on the leftmost monitor, then it appears at the far left edge... never offscreen.)

See attached image for an example. The image shows the mouse cursor over the client-menu icon, and the client menu's actual location offset far to the left.

[image]

I would expect this menu to popup at the cursor position.

Is this some configuration I accidentally set, or some incompatibility with other software, or a bug? Any idea how I can fix it? I am very happy with Openbox otherwise and don't really want to switch to a different window manager.

Comment: I'm running pure openbox on my Ubuntu and sometimes I encounter to a similar problem while right clicking in Firefox ... I don't know what is causing this behavior, it should be a bug I guess...

Comment: I have just the one monitor, and so don't know if the following will be useful: you could, after making a backup, fiddle with  settings in the `placement` section in your `$HOME/.config/openbox/???rc.xml` file. (In a pure Lubuntu that file would be `lubuntu-rc.xml`.)

Comment: I have three monitors, all the same size, arranged in a single desktop. My placement section looks like this:   <placement>
    <policy>UnderMouse</policy>
    <center>no</center>
    <monitor>Mouse</monitor>
    <primaryMonitor>Mouse</primaryMonitor>
  </placement>
I tried changing the settings and reconfiguring openbox after each change, but did not notice any difference.